# Can the equation $1+z+z^q=z^n$ have multiple complex roots $z$?

Tags: co.combinatorics, fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, cv.complex-variables, polynomials

It is proved [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/447134/can-the-equation-1zz2-zn-have-multiple-complex-roots) that the equation $1+z+z^2=z^n$ have no multiple complex roots.

> Q. Let us consider the equation   $1+z+z^q=z^n$ where $q$ and $n$ are natural numbers with $1<q<n$.  Any characterization  for the pair $(q,n)$ such that the equation   $1+z+z^q=z^n$ have no multiple complex roots?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The roots are always simple, this follows without further reasoning from the old paper [On the irreducibility of certain trinomials and quadrinomials](https://doi.org/10.7146/math.scand.a-10593) by Ljunggren. Set $f(z)=z^n-1-z^p-z^q$. Then Ljunggren proves (Theorem 1) that $f(z)=Q(z)g(z)$, where the roots of $Q$ are roots of unity (so $Q=1$ if there are no such roots), and where $g(z)\in\mathbb Q[z]$ is irreducible none of its roots is a root of unity. As an irreducible polynomial, $g$ has no multiple roots. Furthermore (Theorem 2), Ljunggren shows that $Q$ has simple roots either, which settles the question.

Remark: In case Ljunggren's paper is not accessible, [this review at zbMATH](https://zbmath.org/scans/095/013.gif) contains the full statement of Ljunggren's results needed here.

Comment: Great! It is so helpful.

Comment: I tried to examine the problem   for the equations $1+z^p+z^q+z^r=z^n$. But seems one can not follow that by  Ljunggren's paper!  Since I could not find any other idea to figure it out, it is asked in a new problem.

Comment: Could we consider the following as an alternative answer? If there is a multiple root, it should be satisfied $nz^{n-1}-pz^{p-1}-qz^{q-1}=0$.  By a combination with the original equation,     ($z^n-1-z^p-z^q=0$) we may conclude that $(n-p)z^p+(n-q)z^q-n=0$. But this latter (of degree $p$)  divides no polynomial form $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ meaning that the original polynomial   $z^n-1-z^p-z^q=0$ can not have multiple roots! (We are using Gauss  lemma)

Comment: @ABB For this to work you would need to know that your degree $p$ polynomial does not have a monic divisor over $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @ Peter Meuller, if $z^p+\frac{n-q}{n-p}z^q-\frac{n}{n-p}$  divides a monic polynomial from $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ then the  coefficients are all integer which is impossible.

Comment: @ABB But this does not help. Your degree $p$ polynomial could have a monic divisor over $\mathbb Z$. For instance take $f=x^3-x^2$. Then $f'=3x^2-2x$ does not divide a monic polynomial over $\mathbb Z$, but $f$ nevertheless has a multiple root.