# Sufficient conditions for ensuring that a monic polynomial in $\mathbf{Z}[x]$ possesses exclusively simple roots

Tags: real-analysis, cv.complex-variables, polynomials

I am seeking sufficient conditions to ensure that a monic polynomial, denoted as $f$ in  $\mathbf{Z}[x]$, possesses exclusively simple roots.

Based on an old paper ([this reference](https://www.mscand.dk/article/view/10593/8614)), it has been established that polynomials of the form  $f(z)=1+z^p+z^q-z^n$ where $1\leq p< q <n$ exhibit simple roots ([See this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/447164/can-the-equation-1zzq-zn-have-multiple-complex-roots-z)).

> Q. What other general forms of such monic polynomials can be considered?

Comment: In general, this is governed by the (non)vanishing of the discriminant, which is a degree $2n-2$ expression in the coefficients of $f$ that can be computed by a procedure comparable to long division.

Comment: That sounds nice! Could you please give some more details about.

Comment: The question is far to vague to expect a useful answer. For instance, every polynomial which is irreducible, for instance because it is Eisenstein, has no multiple roots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Discriminant is the [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant)
of $f$ and $f'$. In your case, it is simply an integer.
If this integer is $\neq 0$ then $f$ has no multiple root
(and vice versa).