# Can the equation $1+z^p+z^q+z^r=z^n$ have multiple complex roots $z$?

Tags: linear-algebra, ac.commutative-algebra, cv.complex-variables, polynomials

The math overflow [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/447134/can-the-equation-1zz2-zn-have-multiple-complex-roots) asks whether the equation $1+z^p+z^q=z^n$ can have multiple complex roots where $p<q<n$ ([On the irreducibility of certain trinomials and quadrinomials](https://doi.org/10.7146/math.scand.a-10593)).

> Q. Let us consider the polynomial  $\mathbf{P}(z)=1+z^p+z^q+z^r-z^n$ where $p,q,r$ and $n$ are natural numbers with $1<p<q<r<n$. Has $\mathbf{P}$ any  multiple complex root?

Comment: Why does this have a functional analysis tag?

Comment: I found no counter-example up to degree $n=50$ (even allowing $p=1$). There are counter-examples for sums of $6$ monomials, like $1+z+z^2+z^3+z^5-z^7$ which has $z=-1$ as double root.